# Issue with modifier keys on a Windows keyboard under Mac OS X

Tags: macos, keyboard

**Background**

I am using a Windows keyboard on Mac OS X and the modifier keys are laid out like this:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on the Windows keyboard functions as <kbd>Control</kbd> on a Mac keyboard (expected behavior).
- <kbd>Windows Logo Key</kbd> functions as <kbd>Command</kbd> (unexpected behavior).
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> functions as <kbd>Option</kbd> (unexpected as well).

I know that this is probably the way the keys are *supposed* to work, but I'm used to the <kbd>Command</kbd> key where the Alt key is, and the <kbd>Option</kbd> key where the <kbd>Windows Logo</kbd> key is.

I have tried to use the Keyboard preferences pane to switch the <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> keys, but when I do this, only the left modifier keys work.

**My Question:**

So the question is, is there any way to swap the <kbd>Option</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> keys while both left and right modifier keys work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In keyboard preferences there's a "Modifier Keys" button in there that will let you swap modifier keys. I use a PC keyboard with my Mac, and it remembers the choice for my keyboard and the laptop keyboard.

I'm assuming your problem is that the modifier keys to the right of the space key don't swap their functions after using that preference?

[image]

I used to use a preference application called [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/). It might do what you want.